# Do I delete the referenced entity properties in an Entity Framework Code First Model, if I plan on using them with a Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I used the Visual Studio Entity Framework PowerTools to Reverse Engineer Code First model objects for an existing database. I ended up with something like this:

```
namespace PoolVAEFModel.Models
{
    public class Pool
    {
        public Pool()
        {
            this.PoolWaterMetrics = new List<PoolWaterMetric>();
            this.PoolWaterQualities = new List<PoolWaterQuality>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public int WaterCapacityMax { get; set; }
        public int WaterCapacityMin { get; set; }
        public int WaterCapacityRegular { get; set; }
        public string WallMaterial { get; set; }
        public bool IsAboveGroundPool { get; set; }
        public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
        public string SanitationMethod { get; set; }
        public string LocationAddress { get; set; }
        public bool HasHotTop { get; set; }
        public bool JustHotTop { get; set; }
        public int WaterCapacityUnitId { get; set; }
        public double WaterDepthMax { get; set; }
        public double WaterDepthMin { get; set; }
        public int WaterDepthUnitId { get; set; }
        public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
        public virtual Unit Unit1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PoolWaterMetric> PoolWaterMetrics { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PoolWaterQuality> PoolWaterQualities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to use the Repository Pattern to abstract the database layer and was wondering what to do with the referenced entities e.g.

```
    public virtual ICollection<PoolWaterMetric> PoolWaterMetrics { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PoolWaterQuality> PoolWaterQualities { get; set; }
```

Do I just remove the from my class file and just keep the simple properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code first power tools created those navigation collections because you have a mapped foreign key relationship between those tables in the database.  If you're not going to use the navigation properties in your code, feel free to delete, it won't hurt anything.